# Where are the temp airdropped files located in Ventura?

Tags: ventura, airdrop

I know that once the transfer is complete and successful, the files will show up in `Downloads` folder.

Problem is, before the transfer is complete, the file looks to be having zero byte, but when `df -h .` is issued, the `Used` number keeps increasing.

That's why I think there must be a temporary location for airdrop to save the files in transfer. Yet, I can't find where the location is.

Another reason I want to find it out is that I had an unsuccessful airdrop earlier, and I want to delete the intermediate or temporary files generated in that process to save some disk space.

P.S., before asking the question, I've done some research and found [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28124/where-are-airdrop-temp-files-located) post, but that didn't help.

Here's why it didn't help:

```
qxu@xqiang-mac-0:~$ echo $TMPDIR
/var/folders/vb/wc48_w5s5s78kk1ky5ly1x_m0000gn/T/
qxu@xqiang-mac-0:~$ cd /var/folders/vb/wc48_w5s5s78kk1ky5ly1x_m0000gn/T/
qxu@xqiang-mac-0:/var/folders/vb/wc48_w5s5s78kk1ky5ly1x_m0000gn/T$ cd TemporaryItems/
qxu@xqiang-mac-0:/var/folders/vb/wc48_w5s5s78kk1ky5ly1x_m0000gn/T/TemporaryItems$ ls
ls: .: Operation not permitted
```

Update: probably I don't have to worry too much about it. According to [this article on OSXDaily](https://osxdaily.com/2018/08/17/where-temp-folder-mac-access/), the temp files would've been cleared on the next macos reboot.

Comment: idk for sure, but it wouldn't surprise me if it was deep inside `/private/var/folders/` which is not a fun place to play in. It's also very likely tidied itself up by now.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for the suggestion. I took a look at that directory, and the latest folders over there were of 4 days ago, so it couldn't be. I just made a bunch of airdrops today, the first two were unsuccessful.

Comment: My latest folder modified date is May 2022 - yet the contents were changed much more recently, some only seconds ago, hundreds if not thousands in the last month;) You can't use folder mod date like that, unless you're going to dig into every sub-folder. `private/var` is a very busy folder.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I checked that link before posting this question, but that link didn't help.

Comment: @QiangXu Nobody can see what links you've checked before posting this question (and why it didn't help) if you don't mention it in your questions. Please [edit] your question to show your research, indicating what you've found and *why* it didn't help.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke done, and thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is:

> `ls: .: Operation not permitted`

That means that your useraccount `qxu` does not have permission to list the items in `/var/folders/vb/wc48_w5s5s78kk1ky5ly1x_m0000gn/T/TemporaryItems`. Try using the "root" account in the same folder, i.e. `sudo ls`, it will ask for your administrator password and will likely list the contents.

Comment: Tried `sudo`, but the result is the same. :(